# Is there a way to make a POST request on behalf of browser

Tags: javascript, ajax, post, browser

I need to make a POST request with JavaScript but in a way that browser would proceed it. So I need to make it as if any form has been submitted on page, so browser would deal with server response not me in JavaScript code. I only need to attach body and specify URL for request and then I want browser to do the rest. Is there any way to do it except for creating fake form with JS and submitting it?

Comment: I don't think there's any alternative to creating a fake form and submitting it.

Comment: Came up with the same thought. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Ended up creating fake form and submitting it. It doesn't seems too complex but not particularly elegant tho.